# Oracle Apex Checkbox checked on load

Tags: checkbox, oracle-apex

There is a checkbox in my Oracle Apex page. When page load, this checkbox should be checked by default.

I have followed instruction on [How to set Oracle Apex Checkbox default value](http://cglendenningoracle.blogspot.com/2009/10/how-to-set-oracle-apex-checkbox-default.html) and use **Before Footer** as **Computation Point** and **Item Value** as **Computation Type**. But it's not working for me.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Example **Columns Attributes**:

- Display As: Simple Checkbox
- List of values definition: Y,N
- **Default: 'Y'**

Answer (score 0):

Mileage will vary depending on APEX version. That seems the long way - why not set the Default Value attribute of the item?

Is the item associated with a database column?

Comment: Checkbox associated with a database column. If i set Default Value, it always check the checkbox.